# Loading .Rdata Files into Kaggle Notebook

Tags: r, kaggle

I am creating a Kaggle notebook (in R), and I have a saved .Rdata file created locally that I want to load into my Kaggle notebook. Details:

I've uploaded the .Rdata file under my Datasets (even though I cannot see the file there, Kaggle tells me it is there when I try to load it again), then I use a line like below to load the file. I get, however, an error further down?

load("Normdf.Rdata")

Warning message in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE):
“cannot open compressed file 'Normdf.Rdata', probable reason 'No such file or directory'”
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE): cannot open the connection
Traceback:

1. load("Normdf.Rdata")
2. readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE)